# how to retrieve data in string format in Android from SQLite Database

Tags: java, android

I want to retrieve data from SQLite in String format which is used for rating bar. But i'm getting RunTimeException and syntax error and my app is crashes.Can someone help me please.Thanks in advance.

**Here is my Log Cat Info:**

```
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sqlitedemo/com.sqlitedemo.Rating_Details}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Two": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT performance_rate_one, performance_rate_two, performance_rate_three, performance_rate_four, performance_rate_five FROM performance WHERE task_name =Task Two
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Two": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT performance_rate_one, performance_rate_two, performance_rate_three, performance_rate_four, performance_rate_five FROM performance WHERE task_name =Task Two
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at com.sqlitedemo.Rating_Details.showPerformanceRate(Rating_Details.java:63)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at com.sqlitedemo.Rating_Details.onCreate(Rating_Details.java:48)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-25 15:51:06.386: E/AndroidRuntime(28493):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

**Here is my Activity code:**

```
public class Rating_Details extends Activity
{
    String emp_name;
    String task_name;
    String task_date;

    TextView tvEmpNAme;
    TextView tvTaskName;
    TextView tvTaskDate;

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rating_details);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        emp_name = intent.getExtras().getString("EMPNAME");
        task_name = intent.getExtras().getString("TASKNAME");
        task_date = intent.getExtras().getString("DATE");

        System.out.println("____________________________________________________");
        Log.e("emp_name in Rating_Details  "," = " + emp_name);
        Log.e("task_name in Rating_Details "," = " + task_name);
        Log.e("task_date in Rating_Details  "," = " + task_date);

        tvEmpNAme = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_empName);
        tvTaskName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_taskName);
        tvTaskDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_taskDate);

        System.out.println("____________________________________________________");
        tvEmpNAme.setText(emp_name);
        tvTaskName.setText(task_name);
        tvTaskDate.setText(task_date);

        showPerformanceRate();

    }


    private void showPerformanceRate()
    {
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        System.out.println("__________________________________________________________________________________");

        String query = "SELECT performance_rate_one, performance_rate_two, performance_rate_three, performance_rate_four, performance_rate_five FROM performance WHERE task_name =" +task_name;


        Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) 
        { 
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do
                {

                       String strRate1 =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_one"));
                       String strRate2 =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_two"));
                       String strRate3 =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_three"));
                       String strRate4 =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_four"));
                       String strRate5 =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("performance_rate_five"));

                       System.out.println("____________________________________________________");
                       Log.e("strRate1 "," is "+strRate1);
                       Log.e("strRate2 "," is "+strRate2);
                       Log.e("strRate3 "," is "+strRate3);
                       Log.e("strRate4 "," is "+strRate4);
                       Log.e("strRate5 "," is "+strRate5);


                }while (cursor.moveToNext());   
            }
            cursor.close();


        }db.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: `String query = "SELECT performance_rate_one, performance_rate_two, performance_rate_three, performance_rate_four, performance_rate_five FROM performance WHERE task_name ='" +task_name+"'";`

Comment: use parameters ... do not use `'` in the query by yourself ... all those answers are wrong(excpet Sanjeev's) (what if `task_name == "Selvin's task"`)

Comment: Just add (') single quote before and after task_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your string query from:-

```
String query = "SELECT performance_rate_one, performance_rate_two, performance_rate_three, performance_rate_four, performance_rate_five FROM performance WHERE task_name =" +task_name;
```

to

```
String query = "SELECT performance_rate_one, performance_rate_two, performance_rate_three, performance_rate_four, performance_rate_five FROM performance WHERE task_name ='" +task_name+"'";
```

Answer (score 2):

You shall write it like this:

```
   String query = "SELECT performance_rate_one, performance_rate_two, performance_rate_three, performance_rate_four, performance_rate_five FROM performance WHERE task_name =?";


   Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{task_name});
```